# Show that the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ is a regular level set of $f$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ is a regular level set of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$

My understanding of a regular level set is $\{X:f(X)=c\}$ so in this case a level set would be $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}:f(x,y,z)=c\}$.

So I'm not sure what it is I need to show? Since the hyperboloid is already equal to a constant (1) it should then be a level set by definition right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the word "regular". That means that at every point on the level set, the gradient is not zero. That is, $\left< 2x, 2y, -2z \right>$ is not zero for any point on $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$.

Comment: So then it is as simple as saying $\langle 2x,2y,-2z \rangle$ is only zero when $x=y=z=0$ and $0+0-0\ne 1$?

Comment: You should check the definition you are using in your book or class, but yeah, I think so. This is the standard meaning of 1 being a "regular value" of the function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem for instance.